# symfony2 custom annotation translation

Tags: symfony, annotations, translation

Please help me to translate custom annotation.
I'm trying to translate @Render(title="Page"). Translate generator not found this, and title not traslate. 
I try to understand how it is done in the component validation Symfony but nothing happens.

```
<?php
    namespace Shooos\ProductBundle\Controller\Admin;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as PRS;
    use Shooos\CoreBundle\Controller\BaseController;
    use Aft\RenderParkingBundle\Annotations as CA;
    use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Translatable;

    /**
     * @PRS\Route("/admin")
     * Class CategoryController
     * @package Shooos\ProductBundle\Controller\Admin
     */
    class CategoryController extends BaseController
    {
        /**
         * @CA\Render(title="Categories")
         * @PRS\Route("/categories", name="admin.categories")
         */
         public function indexAction()
         {
         }
    }
```

---

```
<?php
namespace Aft\RenderParkingBundle\Annotations\Driver;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Templating\TemplateGuesser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Aft\RenderParkingBundle\Annotations;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class AnnotationDriver
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    private $reader;

    /**
     * @var TemplateGuesser
     */
    private $guesser;

    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(Reader $reader, TemplateGuesser $guesser, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->guesser = $guesser;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * This event occurs when call any controller
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        /** Controller exists */
        if (!is_array($controller = $event->getController())) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Controller
         * @var \ReflectionObject $object
         */
        $object = new \ReflectionObject($controller[0]);
        $method = $object->getMethod($controller[1]);
        foreach ($this->reader->getMethodAnnotations($method) as $configuration) {
            if ($configuration instanceof Annotations\Render) {
                $request = $event->getRequest();

                $title = $this->translator->trans($configuration->getTitle());

                $request->attributes->set('_page_title', $title);

                if (null === $configuration->getTemplate()) {
                    $configuration->setTemplate(
                        $this->guesser->guessTemplateName(
                            $controller,
                            $request
                        ));
                }

                $request->attributes->set('_page_template', $configuration->getTemplate());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us helping you.

Comment: I add a code with user2041082's hint.

Answer (score 1):

On your annotation to object converter, where you inject the annotation reader, inject the translator service and translate the value at the transformation process, from annotation to object.

```
     $description = $this->translator->trans($transformedAnnotationObject->getDescription());
```

Comment: Done - but the translation not generating when execute command
php app/console translation:extract en --bundle=ProductBundle --output-format=yml

Comment: This is a JMSTranslationBundle generator. I guess the translating string should caching by extractor.